# How to detect or prove that this recurrence relation defines a periodic sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, periodic-functions

How to detect or prove that this recurrence relation defines a periodic sequence.

Here is an example $A>0$ is fixed

\begin{align}
f(0) & =0 \\[10pt]
f(x+1) & =
\begin{cases}
    f(x)+1,& \text{if } A\geq f(x)\  \\
    f(x)-1,& \text{if } A<f(x)\ 
\end{cases}
\end{align}

where $A,x$ are natural numbers and the function $f$ returns a natural value.

Can you suggest any method to detect whether this type of recurrence relation defines a periodic sequence?

Comment: Can you see dynamically what this sequence does ? **Hint** Draw a half axis and then - remote - $A$ ($A=10$, for instance) and then start from $0$ and then draw every $f(x)$.

Comment: With the condition $\ldots\land x≥1$ you can't say anything about the function, because you lost a link between the recurrence and the basic definition of $f(0)$. Remove $\ldots\land x≥1$. Also $ \ldots\land A>0$ is unnecessary, as you defined $A$ and $x$ as natural numbers and declare $A>0$.

Comment: If you rewrite the conditions so that $f(x)$ is on the left side of inequality and the constant $A$ on the right, it would easily read _'the function climbs up $\left(f(x+1)=f(x)+1\right)$ as long as it is below (or at) the threshold, and steps down $\left(f(x+1)=f(x)-1\right)$ whenever it's above the threshold'_. Can you imagine now, what happens around $f(x)=A$...?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, for $A$ integer, your sequence is 2-periodic (eventually).

As I indicated you, a drawing makes it clear that, if you suppose $A\in \mathbb{Z}$, you have two cases

1. If $A\geq 0$, then your sequence increases (with $1$-steps) until it reaches $A$ then goes to $A+1$, then
   $$
   A,\ A+1, A,\ A+1,A,\ A+1 \ldots
   $$

   If $A<0$, then your sequence decreases (with $1$-steps) until it reaches $A$ then goes to $A+1$, then
   $$
   A,\ A+1, A,\ A+1,A,\ A+1 \ldots
   $$

in each case it is eventually periodic.

Hope it helps.